# Change massive header gap in Pages 09

Tags: macos, iwork-pages, iwork-09

A couple of the default Pages templates have these very big headers on the very first page (usually the cover page), with no visible way of removing it.

How can I modify the page to remove this massive gap? It is getting in the way when I don't want a title page and I would love for it to be removed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sample you’ve provided (The Astronomy 101 Report) what you need to do is to go to the Inspector, then Layout and then change the "Layout Margins”, the “Before” has like 4 Cm, which is the space you see between the header and the green title.

In other cases, you might always want to check the “Format -> Advanced” menu. In particular the *make master objects selectable*.

Those usually help a lot, as well as “show invisibles” and all that stuff.